# mongoid does not update the right objects of an embedded collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a document Portfolio with an array of embedded docs PortfolioItem portfolio_items. Each of those has another array of Image images. Somehow I can update the first object in the array like here:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/portfolios/5436dc1c646172844b000000/portfolio_items/5436dc27646172844b010000/images/5436dc40646172844b020000" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-14 17:06:13 -0300
Processing by Admin::ImagesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hHz3W90KMgGK+LGtjLMGQmx295tvva6IFIcD4gqgG+8=", "image"=>{"title"=>"img 1", "description"=>"", "technique"=>"", "date"=>"", "public"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Atualizar Image", "portfolio_id"=>"5436dc1c646172844b000000", "portfolio_item_id"=>"5436dc27646172844b010000", "id"=>"5436dc40646172844b020000"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=portfolio_development collection=admins selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4cb5fbc04174a17926000002')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 1.2910ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=portfolio_development collection=portfolios selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc1c646172844b000000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 2.6960ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=portfolio_development collection=portfolios selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc1c646172844b000000'), "portfolio_items._id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc27646172844b010000'), "portfolio_items.0.images._id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc40646172844b020000')} update={"$set"=>{"portfolio_items.0.images.$.public"=>false}} flags=[]
                         COMMAND      database=portfolio_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.2640ms
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/portfolios/5436dc1c646172844b000000/portfolio_items/5436dc27646172844b010000/images/5436dc40646172844b020000/edit
Completed 302 Found in 21ms
```

but if I try to update another one, with the equivalent output, which relates correctly to the object I want to update

```
Started PATCH "/admin/portfolios/5436dc1c646172844b000000/portfolio_items/5436dc27646172844b010000/images/5436de41646172844b040000" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-14 17:03:04 -0300
Processing by Admin::ImagesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hHz3W90KMgGK+LGtjLMGQmx295tvva6IFIcD4gqgG+8=", "image"=>{"title"=>"img 3", "description"=>"", "technique"=>"", "date"=>"", "public"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Atualizar Image", "portfolio_id"=>"5436dc1c646172844b000000", "portfolio_item_id"=>"5436dc27646172844b010000", "id"=>"5436de41646172844b040000"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 1.0710ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=portfolio_development collection=admins selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4cb5fbc04174a17926000002')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 1.0460ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=portfolio_development collection=portfolios selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc1c646172844b000000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 2.8700ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=portfolio_development collection=portfolios selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc1c646172844b000000'), "portfolio_items._id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436dc27646172844b010000'), "portfolio_items.0.images._id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5436de41646172844b040000')} update={"$set"=>{"portfolio_items.0.images.$.public"=>false}} flags=[]
                         COMMAND      database=portfolio_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.2790ms
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/portfolios/5436dc1c646172844b000000/portfolio_items/5436dc27646172844b010000/images/5436de41646172844b040000/edit
Completed 302 Found in 26ms
```

I actually update another object in the same collection (with, of course, a different id), namely, again, the first object in the collection.

The controller code selects the right objects, it is the update that seems to create this mess. Anyone has an idea, what I could do about it?

Here is what happens in my controller, but I cannot detect an error there, the correct objects were always selected:

```
class Admin::ImagesController < Admin::AdminController

  before_filter :find_parents

  def find_parents
    @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])
    @portfolio_item = @portfolio.portfolio_items.find(params[:portfolio_item_id])
    if params[:id]
      @image = @portfolio_item.images.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def update
    @image.update_attributes(image_params)
    if @image.valid?
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = t('simple_form.error_notification.default_message')
      render template: 'admin/images/edit'
    end
  end

 def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :technique, :date, :image, :public, :delete_image)
 end

end
```

Also I not getting any error message.

Here is a console session, that shows the behavior pretty clearly

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
[1] pry(main)> p = Portfolio.last
=> #<Portfolio _id: 5436dc1c646172844b000000, index: 4, public: true, title: "test portfolio", _slugs: ["test-portfolio"], description: "">
[2] pry(main)> i = p.portfolio_items.first
=> #<PortfolioItem _id: 5436dc27646172844b010000, index: 0, public: true, title: "test item", _slugs: ["test-item"], client: "", description: "", date: nil>
[3] pry(main)> imgs = i.images
=> [#<Image _id: 5436dc40646172844b020000, index: 1, public: false, title: "i was changed", _slugs: ["img-4", "i-was-changed-1"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 5436dc4b646172844b030000, index: 0, public: false, title: "img 2", _slugs: ["img-2"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 5436de41646172844b040000, index: 2, public: true, title: "img 3", _slugs: ["img-3"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 543d7ada6461722ec0010000, index: 3, public: false, title: "img 4", _slugs: ["img-4"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>]
[4] pry(main)> img = imgs[3]
=> #<Image _id: 543d7ada6461722ec0010000, index: 3, public: false, title: "img 4", _slugs: ["img-4"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>
[5] pry(main)> img.title = 'i was changed'
=> "i was changed"
[6] pry(main)> img.save
=> true
[7] pry(main)> img.reload
=> #<Image _id: 543d7ada6461722ec0010000, index: 3, public: false, title: "img 4", _slugs: ["img-4"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>
[8] pry(main)> 
[9] pry(main)> p = p.reload
=> #<Portfolio _id: 5436dc1c646172844b000000, index: 4, public: true, title: "test portfolio", _slugs: ["test-portfolio"], description: "">
[10] pry(main)> i = p.portfolio_items.first
=> #<PortfolioItem _id: 5436dc27646172844b010000, index: 0, public: true, title: "test item", _slugs: ["test-item"], client: "", description: "", date: nil>
[11] pry(main)> imgs = i.images
=> [#<Image _id: 5436dc40646172844b020000, index: 1, public: false, title: "i was changed", _slugs: ["img-4", "i-was-changed"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 5436dc4b646172844b030000, index: 0, public: false, title: "img 2", _slugs: ["img-2"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 5436de41646172844b040000, index: 2, public: true, title: "img 3", _slugs: ["img-3"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>, #<Image _id: 543d7ada6461722ec0010000, index: 3, public: false, title: "img 4", _slugs: ["img-4"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>]
[12] pry(main)> img = imgs[3]
=> #<Image _id: 543d7ada6461722ec0010000, index: 3, public: false, title: "img 4", _slugs: ["img-4"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>
[13] pry(main)> changed = imgs.select {|x| x.title == 'i was changed'}
=> [#<Image _id: 5436dc40646172844b020000, index: 1, public: false, title: "i was changed", _slugs: ["img-4", "i-was-changed"], description: "", technique: "", date: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, image_fingerprint: nil>]
[14] pry(main)> changed = imgs.select {|x| x.title == 'i was changed'}
```

Models:

- Portfolio https://gist.github.com/janlimpens/81b70a45484f83765603
- PortfolioItem https://gist.github.com/janlimpens/bdfccb76e7db4ea7a8a9
- Image https://gist.github.com/janlimpens/478a3e9059032eae454b

And for total mindboggling wtfing pleaseure - a tests that does not fail:

```
test 'the correct image is updated' do
      p = FactoryGirl.create(:portfolio)
      item = FactoryGirl.create(:portfolio_item)
      image1 = FactoryGirl.create(:image)
      image2 = FactoryGirl.create(:image)
      image3 = FactoryGirl.create(:image)
      item.images << image1
      item.images << image2
      item.images << image3
      p.portfolio_items << item
      assert(p.valid?)
      p.save
      pos = 0..2

      pos.each do |i|
        title =  "Hello World #{i}"
        pt= Portfolio.first
        pt.portfolio_items[0].images[i].title = title
        pt.save
        pt.reload

        assert(pt.portfolio_items[0].images[i].title == title)
        pp pt.portfolio_items[0].images.map { |x| x.title }
      end
end
```

Comment: That's weird, can you print the img object before and after save in your pry session? to see if any inconsistencies exit ?

Comment: @Ali, I updated it and seems everything seems to be as wrong as expected ;)

Comment: @Chris, The wrong image in the portfolio_item's images collection is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just found out that this is a mongoDB bug that bites me here (why in the webapp and not in the test is a bit unclear to me, but that's another story). The issue is:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831
and a consequence to updating mongodb to 2.6.

Comment: From what I heard, this ought to be fixed in mongodb 2.7

Answer (score 0):

try after

```
[6] pry(main)> img.save
```

**img.reload**

try to reload model object after manipulations, from http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html :

```
label.bands.push(band)

label.bands #=> [ band ]
band.update_attribute(:active, false)
label.bands #=> [ band ] Must reload.
label.reload.bands #=> []
```

Comment: give answer more detail

Comment: try to reload model object after manipulations, or try something like this:

Comment: @Jan mb 'i = p.portfolio_items.first; img = i.images.where(:title => 'i was changed');' img will give you array